# Ruby on Rails: How to model Organisations and Clients?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an application where a **User** can have many **Clients** (which cannot be shared among Users).

It is a fairly small application but it *could* happen that two **Clients** belong to the same **Organisation**. So it would be nice to have an extra table to hold all the information about the Organisation. It could also happen that a Client is a private Client and does *not* belong to any Organisation.

I know in database design this is fairly common, but how can this be modelled in Rails?

Comment: Lots of info missing: can a client be shared among users? can two clients from the same org be related to different users? more than who "has many", it's important to know who "belongs to", that is, whether any object has a strictly "to-one" relation with another. Example: a client belongs to an organization, a user "belongs to" a language (in the sense that the user has as an attribute the spoken language) and to a city, etc. it's "belonging" in the sense of "has as property/attribute"

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing this out. I slightly changed my initial question above. There should be no sharing of Clients among Users (One User should not see another User's Clients at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is what have been stated by @peter-duijnstee, with the additional constraints asked:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, :presence => true
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization

  # note the final "s", it validates a field
  validates :user, :presence => true 

  # no final "s", validate using a method
  validate :organization_user, :if => :organization_present?

  def organization_present?
    organization.present?
  end

  def organization_user
    errors.add(:organization_id, "is not allowed") unless organization.user_id == user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. This is a fairly new concept for a Rails n00b like me. I am still trying to fully understand your code. Can anybody point me to any tutorial or provide a keyword that I can search for? Is *Single table inheritance* something that is concerned here?

Comment: STI has nothing to do here. You have just a couple of plain one-to-many relations, with a constraint that client->org->user must coincide with client->user whenever there is an org.

Answer (score 1):

How does an organization relate to the users? If users and organizations are independent from each other the simplest solution would be to have...

```
User         - has_many :clients
Organization - has_many :clients
Client       - belongs_to :user, belongs_to :organization
```

But I'm guessing there's more involved here? Are you looking for a many-to-many solution?

Comment: Yes, I think we are close to it here. (I also updated my initial question above.) The only pitfall now is that a Client will not necessarily be part of an Organisation. How can this be modelled?

Comment: Seems like Saverio has a more complete answer for you. As for dependencies, if you don't specify otherwise they are never required. You can just create a client without a user or without an organization if you so choose (unless you specify otherwise your model.) In that case client.user or client.organization would return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
User has many clients.
Client belongs to user.
```

This is fairly simple.  The "clients" table would have a foreign key "user_id" if you're using a relational database.

Between clients and organizations, is it One-to-Many? or Many-to-Many?
If it's one-to-many, you can do

```
Organization has many clients.
Client belongs to organization.
```

If it's many-to-many, you would need a mapping table

```
Organization has and belongs to many clients.
Client has and belongs to many organizations.
```

Learn more about associations in Rails ActiveRecord [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)